# background mode in ios by audio being killed by other apps

Tags: ios, audio, multitasking

Recently,I try to make an app needs working in background and I use audio to protect the app from being killed by ios.Neither voip nor bluetooth,and not a Luckily,the demo works well until a new app execute which also run in background and also run by something audio.Then the demo was killed after 10 mins later,can anyone help me with the trouble?There must be other Thanks!!later i found an new app which do well in background mode.And here is the url :https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pacer-pedometer-plus-weight/id600446812?mt=8 ,Sorry ,i'm not good at in English..
    - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application{
    if(counter==0){
        [player play];
        // Registers this class as the delegate of the audio session.
        [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate: self];
        [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: nil];

```
    UInt32 doSetProperty = 0;
    //The C Style function call
    AudioSessionSetProperty (
                             kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers,
                             sizeof (doSetProperty),
                             &doSetProperty
                             );
    // Activates the audio session.
    NSError *activationError = nil;
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: &activationError];

    [player setDelegate:self];

    //play audio
    [player play];
    [self backgroundHandler];
}
```

}